# How to change DB user password for CiviCRM 4.7.3?

Tags: civicrm.settings.php

For my own reasons, I needed to change the Civi database user password. After doing so in my hosts CP, this of course broke CiviCRM (WP). I'm a Civi newbie so I was expecting I might be able to easily find the file to change the pw like WP's wpconfig file. No such luck.

What files and their locations must I change so I can reconnect Civi to its DB?

Answer (score 3):

Supplementing Jason's answer for a Drupal installation: the file civicrm.settings.php will be found in your site's directory, e.g. drupal/sites/default/ or drupal/sites/mysite.com/ . Look for `CIVICRM_DSN` in civicrm.settings.php .

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out and for the benefit of anyone who might Google search this same question, here's the answer.
 1. Go to your webhost's file browser.
 2. The file should be located in /public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
 3. Open the file with the code editor.
 4. Modify the credentials string which contains the password and save.